# Does it matter if function returns T or object if T can not be inferred from context?

Tags: java, object, generics, wildcard

I found the following source code in [gson](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.reflect.Type-):

```
public <T> T fromJson(Reader json, Type typeOfT) throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException
{
    JsonReader jsonReader = newJsonReader(json);
    T object = (T) fromJson(jsonReader, typeOfT);
    assertFullConsumption(object, jsonReader);
    return object;
}
```

Does it matter if *fromJson* function declares to return an *Object* or return *T*? at least from my knowledge, if the T can not be inferred by function arguments it acts exactly as object.
So why the source code uses *T* instead of an *Object*?

Comment: It does matter. They provide T so that the type can be inferred. `Foo foo = gson.fromJson(reader, type);` If it were Object you would have to cast it yourself. So it is written that way for convenience. Of course, their cast is still unchecked so the method basically assumes the caller is assigning to the right type. If they are not then they will get a class cast exception.

Comment: @Michael, which check they could add?

Comment: This is google's code. If there were one, they would do it ;) This is a consequence of type erasure, and the fact that the return T and the parameter Type are unrelated as far as the compiler is concerned. The only relation between them is contextual. There is nothing to stop me calling `String s = gson.fromJson(reader, TypeOfInteger)`, which is destined to fail

Comment: @Michael, thank you. Maybe you can look at *xehpuk* example, and try  to understand why *result2* assignment doesn't throw an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't return `Object` but a type that's either inferred from the context or – if that's not possible – by passing a type parameter with a [*type witness*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html): `YourClass.<String>fromJson()`

Note that this won't magically work. If the object that's returned from the internal call isn't compatible with `T` at runtime, the assignment (of the outer return value) will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String result1 = MyClass.test(); // works as expected
        Object result2 = MyClass.<Integer>test(); // works "surprisingly"
        int result3 = MyClass.test(); // cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    }
    
    static <T> T test() {
        try {
            return (T) "Hello World";
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new Error(); // never reached
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Michael You are absolutely correct. Hope it's better now.

Comment: thanks. Three small things: 1.When saying *If the object that's returned from the internal call isn't compatible with T at runtime*, who is T? Is it who serves as result1,result2,result3 in your example?
2. Who can say why result2 assignment doesn't throw an exception?
3.Is the casting *(T)* in the return statement necessary?

Comment: @Eitanos30 `T` is inferred from the left-hand side of the assignment, yes. It is not constrained by the parameters, so the constraint comes from the return type.  So in the above examples `T` is first String, then Object, then Integer. `result2` doesn't throw an exception because Object variables can store anything -- that is, Object is not special, it's just the widest/least-specific type there is.  So `result2` works because `Object a = new Integer(1)` is valid. However, `Integer a = new Object()` is obviously not

Comment: @Michael Any idea when explicitly providing `T` would change anything?

Comment: That "explicitly providing `T`" thingy is called a type witness (just in case it helps you google it to learn more). They are useful in some situations, mostly you use them when the compiler cannot infer the correct type. In this situation, no, they seem useless.

Comment: @Michael, Does <Integer> as any  influence here? I thought is role is to sign that the parameter type is  Integer, but it feels like it being ignored

Comment: In this example it has no influence at all. What you have to remember is that generics are compile-time only. They are erased. So as long as it compiles, generics are happy. In this case, the generics think we have an integer assigned to an object, so they are satisfied. We humans know that there's a String cast to - what seems to be - an integer in there (in reality, it is cast to Object, i.e. nothing happens -- the cast is removed in the bytecode), but casts are our way of overruling the compiler so that's fine. At runtime, all we're left with is a String being assigned to an Object variable

Comment: @Michael Thank you!